# Why is Thunderbird plagued by duplicate messages? Is this a Thunderbird crock or an IMAP server crock?

Tags: thunderbird, imap

The Mozilla Thunderbird email client is generally quite nice, but recently I have been plagued with many, many duplicate messages.  After some Googling I discovered that there is an Add-on which will remove duplicates.  It does have me seriously considering a new client but first I'd like to see if the real cause of the problem is understood and whether is lies with Thunderbird or with the server (Dovecot/Fedora 10 in this case).

Comment: Are they really duplicate messages or just lots of spam messages all the same? **UPDATE** Is there any pattern to the duplicated messages? Do they have the wrong date stamp set in the future?. If so it could be that the server and/or Thunderbird thinks they're still new messages as they were "received" after the last time it checked.

Comment: They really truly are duplicates and the add-on really detects and gets rid of them.  Leaving the messages on the server is the whole point of using IMAP, at least for me since I use multiple machines daily, frequently simultaneously.  And it is only SOME messages, i.e. some SPAM messages and some non-SPAM messages.

Comment: Since you're using IMAP you can try another client - do you have webmail access to the server, or can you try Outlook Express or something else?  Use it for a while, just long enough to see if it's Thunderbird that's causing the problem.

Comment: As for the obvious, assuming you have webmail access as well: in the webmail you only see those messages once, right? (If there's no dedicated webmail then you could see the messages using, for example, http://www.mail2web.com)

Comment: If you have the "leave messages on server" option enabled, they may register as duplicates even though you've already downloaded them into the local folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stupid timeout + retry behavior, the IMAP server I'm administering just got folders with 3 days old messages duplicated over 600 times...
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=403603